# Video source invalid format issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I test against an invalid .mp4  format file in order to hide the corresponding container?

```
<div id="video">
    <video controls width="320" height="240">
        <source src="<?php echo $row["username"]);?>" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Here is my attempt:

```
<script>
    document._video = document.getElementById("video");

    document._video.addEventListener('error',function(){
        video.style.display = "none";
     });
</script>
```

Comment: you mean catch and handle errors from the video element?

Comment: also you need to do `document._video.style.display = "none"`

Answer (score 1):

why not work? because you addeventlistener to div not the source of video tag

```
<div id="video">
      <video controls="controls" width="320" height="240">
          <source src="aaaa" type="video/mp4"/>
      </video>
  </div>

<script>
    var v = document.querySelector('#video');
    var sources = v.querySelectorAll('source');

    if (sources.length !== 0) {
        var lastSource = sources[sources.length-1];

        lastSource.addEventListener('error', function() {
            v.style.display="none";
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [canPlayType()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canPlayType):

The possible return values are:

- **probably**: The specified media type appears to be playable.
- **maybe**: Cannot tell if the media type is playable without playing it.
- **'' (empty string)**: The specified media type definitely cannot be played.

If, instead you need the [onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/onerror) in order to get

> ....These events occur when some form of error occurs while attempting to load or perform the media.

your code must be changed to:

```
$('#video source').on('error',function(e) {
```

The snippet:

```js
var result = $('#video video').get(0).canPlayType($('#video video source').attr('type'));

console.log('The first video can be played: ' + result);

$('#video source').on('error',function(e) {
    //
    // this in order to dectect wrong sources
    //
    $('#video').toggle();
    console.log('The first video source has errors...');
});

$('#newvideo source').on('error',function(e) {
    //
    // this in order to dectect wrong sources
    //
    $('#newvideo').toggle();
    console.log('The second video source has errors...');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="video">
    <p>The first video: it's ok</p>
    <video controls width="320" height="240">
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>

<!-- This second video has an invalid source -->
<div id="newvideo">
    <p>The second video: it has an invalid source</p>
    <video controls width="320" height="240">
        <source src="aaaaaa" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```